# how to cut the dendrogram with VARCLUS in R (package Hmisc)

Tags: r

I want to perform variable clustering using the `varclus()` function from `Hmisc` package.
However I do not know how to put clusters of variables into a table if I cut the dendrogram into 10 clusters of variable.

I used to use

```
groups <- cutree(hclust(d), k=10)
```

to cut dendrograms of individuals but it doesn't work for variables.

Comment: Drop us some example code to play with.

Comment: Maybe `cutree(varclus(d)$hclust, k=10)` is what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Anatoliy's comment, you indeed use the same `cutree()` function 
 as before because the clustering done in `varclus()` is actually done by the `hclust()` function.

When you use `varclus()` you're creating an object of class `varclus` that contains a `hclust` object - which can be referenced by using `$hclust`.

Example:

```
x <- varclus(d)
x_hclust <- x$hclust  ## retrieve hclust object

groups <- cutree(x_hclust, 10)
```